# Connected spaces and open continuous maps.

Tags: general-topology

Let  $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous, open and surjective map, such that $f^{-1}(y)\subseteq X$ is connected for all $y\in Y$ and $Y$ is a connected space. Show that $X$ is connected.

I'm looking for any eventual mistake in my reasoning:

Suppose $X=A \sqcup B$ with $A, B$ open disjoint sets $\neq X, \emptyset$. For surjectivity I know $f(X)=f(A \sqcup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)=Y$. I know both $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are open in $Y$, being $f$ an open map, and $\neq \emptyset$ therefore $f(A) \cap f(B) \neq \emptyset$. Let $y\in f(A) \cap f(B)$ there exist $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$ so $x_1, x_2 \in f^{-1}(y)$ are connected, meaning there exists a connected set $X \supseteq C \ni x_1, x_2$.

Now $C\cap A \ni x_1$ and $C\cap B \ni x_2$ are both non empty open sets and $C=(C\cap A) \sqcup (C\cap B)$: contraddiction because $C$ is connected. So $X$ is not union of disjoint open sets, so it's connected.

Is this ok?

Comment: It seems correct to me, and ur set $C$ is simply $C=f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: @TomásPacheco I see, thank you.